# I can't find a single word that starts with the "Sa" sound in "saga"

Tags: syllables

I've read every word starting with "SA" in my dictionary out loud.  It's driving me crazy thinking there is only a single English word starting with what appears to be such a common syllable.

Is it my Midwestern American accent?  What makes "saga" special?

Comment: Try *Soggy* or *somnolent*. The spelling doesn't necessarily determine the pronunciation.

Comment: There are several minor variations of the pronunciation of the "sa" sound in that context.  I would say that "sagacious" comes close, but others would likely pronounce it slightly differently.

Comment: There is more than one pronunciation of "saga". According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saga), it can have the vowel of "father" or the vowel of "sag".

Comment: I'm specifically looking to match the Japanese さ.  The little munchkin in my avatar is my son Sasuke, who sadly has no nickname.

Comment: What words are close to the same vowel for you? For me, it's the vowel of the first syllable of *samba* and *noggin*. Closer to the *cot* vowel rather than *caught*, if you aren't merged, so for me different from the first vowel in *sauna*. Definitely not the vowel in *sag* or *cat*. But ymmv, so it would help to get a better sense of what vowel you mean.

Comment: I don't pronounce the "r" in *sardonic*, so the two words start with the same sound for me. I'm blown away at the *other* pronunciation of "saga" - sounds quite bizarre to me! I'd love to know what countries or regions pronounce it that way: is it just AmE?

Comment: @Chappo: I tried looking at the pronunciation of "saga" on Youglish. Based on the clips I saw so far, the "sag" pronunciation seems pretty uncommon, and I did only hear it from American English speakers.

Comment: What makes it 'special' is that it's a Scandinavian word which has been borrowed into English. As anyone who has watched _The Bridge_ knows, the Swedes (and Norwegians) say 'sahga', the Danes say 'sayga'.

Comment: Sob, sock, sod...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phonetic translation of the word 'saga' is **sɑːɡə**.

There exist a many number of words that share the same sound of "sa", or in other words, the **sɑː** sound.

A few such words include:

1. Cryosar
2. Sardonic
3. Quasar
4. Sarcophagus
5. Arkansas (although proper, it still has the same **sɑː** pronunciation)
6. Sardines

Similarly many more exist.

Comment: ...if the speaker is non-rhotic.

Comment: @Chappo I may not have much rep on this site, but my dad grew up in Arkansas and I’m a Texan, and I have to say we both pronounce the *sas* in *Arkansas* identically to the *sa* in *saga*.

Comment: Perfect! I'm from Wisconsin for what it's worth.  Sardine is the winner for me, starts with the same 'sa' and is a word everyone knows.  Thanks!

Comment: @sumelic I should stick to using IPA, especially since I'm no expert in phonetics! So, as an Australian I pronounce the last syllable of *Arkansas* as /soː/ whereas MW gives the primary pronunciation as /sȯ/ - a subtle difference. I'm intrigued that you pronounce it /sɑ/ - is this collateral damage from the cot-caught merger? ;-) But seriously (and for my better understanding), wouldn't that merger turn it into a /sɒ/? And do you pronounce the first syllable of *saga* as /sɑ/ too?

Comment: @Chappo: In almost all American English accents, /ɒ/ does not exist as a sound distinct from /ɑ/ and /ɔ/. The vowel in words like "lot" has merged with the vowel of the word "father", and the merged vowel is typically transcribed as /ɑ/. (In a few other words, like "cloth", the vowel instead merged with the "thought" vowel /ɔ/, which Merriam-Webster writes as "ȯ"--MW does not use IPA transcription.) For speakers with the cot-caught merger like me, /ɑ/ has additionally replaced the "thought"/"cloth" vowel. So I have /sɑ/ in all of ***sa**ga, **so**ccer, **sau**sage, **sough**t, Arkan**sas**.*

Comment: @herisson Having been born and raised (a little) east of the Mississippi, I have /sɑ/ only in ***sa**ga, **so**ck, **so**t, **so**ccer, **sa**ns, **sa**ké, **sa**ndhi, **Sa**ppho* — whereas I have /sɔ/  in all of ***saw**n, **sal**t, Jonas **Sal**k, **sau**na,  **sal**sa, **sau**té, **psal**m, **sol**ve, **sau**sage, **sau**cer, **sough**t, Arkan**sas***. Never having lived in a region with the merger nor being an especially avid consumer of SoCal-produced media, it forever jars me to hear the second set pronounced like the first, slowing me down a bit as I figure out which word was said.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of words that start with the "sah" sound. They're typically words we've adopted from another language, but are now accepted English words. The following are from Merriam-Webster, starting with the comparison word; note that MW provides an audio clip on each page so you can get an idea of how each is pronounced.

[saga](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saga)

> \ ˈsä-gə \

[sadhu](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sadhu)

> \ ˈsä-(ˌ)dü \
>   : a usually Hindu mendicant ascetic

[sahib](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sahib)

> \ ˈsä-ˌ(h)ib \
>   : SIR, MASTER —used especially among the native inhabitants of
>   colonial India when addressing or speaking of a European of some
>   social or official status

[sake (2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sake)

> \ ˈsä-kē \
>   : a Japanese alcoholic beverage of fermented rice often served hot

Certain words starting with *sar-* that are either monosyllabic or have the stress on the first syllable **may** have the same pronunciation as the first syllable of *saga*, depending on whether the speaker is [non-rhotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English). Candidates include *sarcasm*, *sarcous*, *sard*, *sarge*, *sari*, *sark*, *sarmentose*, *saros* and *sarsen*. One of these is sufficient as an example (again relying on MW's dictionary entry):

[sard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sard)

> \ ˈsärd \
>   : a reddish-brown variety of chalcedony sometimes classified as a
>   variety of carnelian

Comment: You’re right that most of these are imports, or in arrhotic speakers. See [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/481353/i-cant-find-a-single-word-that-starts-with-the-sa-sound-in-saga#comment1339467_481357) for a scant few more with /sɑ/ for me as an [Inland North speaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English). That means I have neither the *cot–caught* merger nor the *cot–cart* merger. Being older and more rural in origin than metropolitan, I also lack the more recent Northern Cities Vowel Shift.